# PL/SQL Case with Group By and Pivot

Tags: plsql

I have data that I'm presenting in an APEX interactive report, using a pivot statement to display monthly data for a period of 15 years.  I am color coding some of the values based on if it contains a decimal using a case statement.

My problem is that by using the case statement, it is creating multiple rows from one row of data.  My report is showing 2 rows for each item, one for the row containing values without decimals, and one row with values containing decimals.

[Multiple Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcKwJ.jpg)

How can I combine the rows into one?  Use a Group By? or is there a better way?

```
select buscat, prod_parent, year_month, volume, load_source, tstamp,
   case when instr(VOLUME, '.') > 0 then 'color:#FF7755;' else 'color:#000000;' end flag
 from HISTORY where id > 0
```

Here is raw data from SQL query...

[SQL return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Uie.jpg)

Comment: Sample data would help here. Also, this looks like q question about Oracle SQL not PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SQL Return image the data is not repeating. It looks like you are not filtering for 'Volume == 0'. Try changing 'ID' to 'volume' in where clause:

```
select yearMonth, volume, load_source, tstamp,
    case when instr(volume, '.') > 0 then 'color:#FF7755;' else 'color:#000000;' end flag
from HISTORY 
where volume > 0
```